# CloudBlob.DownloadText method inserts additional character?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The following unit test fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Add_file_to_blob_and_retrieve_it()
{
    var blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var testFileContents = File.ReadAllText(TestFileSpec);

    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Opening blob container {0}", UnitTestBlobAgentName));
    CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(
            (configName, configSetter) => configSetter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName]));
    var cloudStorage = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("StorageConnectionString");
    var blobClient = cloudStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(UnitTestBlobAgentName.ToLower());

    try
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Uploading file {0}", TestFileSpec));
        var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
        blob.UploadFile(TestFileSpec);
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "ByteArray";
        blob.SetProperties();
        var blob1 = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
        var found = blob1.DownloadText();
        Assert.AreEqual(testFileContents.Trim(), found.Trim());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != container)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Deleting blob {0}", blobName));
            var blob2 = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
            blob2.DeleteIfExists(new BlobRequestOptions { DeleteSnapshotsOption = DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots });
        }
    }
}
```

It turns out, the returned string begins with the dword `0xFEFF` (the Unicode BOM). I've traced through the Microsoft debug symbols, and the BOM exists in the return stream. AFAICT, it comes from the `HttpResponse.GetResponseStream()` method call way down in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob` class.

What's the best way to ensure that the input and output are identical? Ensure the input is converted to Unicode before going in? Strip the BOM from the output? Any other ideas?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to `UTF8.GetString()` and `UTF8.GetBytes()`. Have you tried using `DownloadByteArray()` instead of `DownloadStream()`, which calls DownloadByteArray, then encodes to string with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`... and same thing with `UploadByteArray()`, which is called by `UploadText()`.

Comment: Have you checked "Character Encoding issue with CopyBlob API" which suggest different way to encode blob before upload/download? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/05/28/character-encoding-issues-related-to-copy-blob-api.aspx

Comment: I created an extension method `DownloadString` for `CloudBlockBlob` and used the same code which is used in `WebClient.DownloadString`. Here you can find the code: [How to get rid of BOM when downloading text from azure blob](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/how-to-get-rid-of-bom-when-downloading-text-from-azure-blob/)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old one, but if your blob is encoded as Unicode in azure, and you want to download it to a text string, this code will do the trick. Just keep in mind, the weakness here is that you've got to allocate the memory twice. If there's a more efficient way of getting to a Unicode string (synchronously, anyway,) I couldn't find it.

```
string fileText;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    cloudBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        fileText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```